# All I get is "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" error

Tags: python, nameerror

I am new to python and I am trying to make a function that calculates the derivative of another function. So far I have this code

```
def f(x):
   return x**2 + x - 5

def derivative(f,x,h):
    return 1/(2*h) * (f(x+h) - f(x-h))

print derivative(f(x),4,6)
```

but when I try to run it I get "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" error, can someone help me?

Comment: From your function signatures it looks like you meant to call it like `print derivative(f(4),4,6)` where `x = 4`.

Comment: I am trying to make a function that calculates the derivative of a function if that makes sense, I am only given the "1/(2*h) * (f(x+h) - f(x-h))" line and the answer must be in "float". Maybe I am going about this all wrong...

Comment: The main point is as it stands Erik you are not giving a value to your f(x) function to use for x.

Answer (score 3):

x is not defined, and you cannot pass f(x) in the parameter.
Try doing something like this:

```
def f(x):
return x**2 + x - 5

def derivative(f,x,h):
return 1/(2*h) * (f(x+h) - f(x-h))

x=12345

print derivative(f,x,6)
```

Comment: This would throw the same error as f is not defined. I think you meant f(x) as the OP had it originally.

Comment: Not on my system.  I had to remove the (x) from f(x) on the last line. (2.7.10 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)])

Comment: Hmm.... currently you are telling it to go the function derivative and execute with the parameters of variable f's value, variable x's value and the integer 6. That would compute to `return 1/(2*6) * (f(UNDEFINED)(x(UNDEFINED)+6) - f(UNDEFINED)(x(UNDEFINED)-6))` . I should add that even if that works it is not exactly what the OP is attempting do because he wants to calculate the return value of x being passed through the  first function and use  that as a the 1st parameter of the second function .Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Ha, true.  We will never know.  His variable names are not the best choices.

Comment: I want the function "x^2+x´-5" go through my second function where the second function calculates the derivative of "x^2+x-5" in the point "x"
so
f = should be "x^2+x-5"
x = in which point I want to calculate the derivative

Comment: So you really do want to pass the function f.  You don't want to pass the return of f(x).  In which case, I stand by my answer.

Comment: So just to be clear, I would rename references in both functions to use different variable names for f. Like def samplePolynomial(x), and def derivative(f,x,h).

Answer (score 2):

When you tell it to :

```
print derivative(f(x),4,6)
```

you haven't defined the x you are passing as a parameter in f(x).

You can do that like so, for example with  x = 1 :

```
def f(x):
   return x**2 + x - 5

def derivative(f,x,h):
    return 1/(2*h) * (f(x+h) - f(x-h))

x=1

print derivative(f(x),4,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

class Assign:

```
def _init_(self,x,y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y

def sub(self,x,y):
    return x-y 

num1 = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))

obj=Assign()

if x<=0:
    print(num1,"-",num2,"=","he's the messiah he's a very naughty boy", obj.sub(num1,num2))

elif x>=0:
    print(num1,"-",num2,"=","Yes we all are individuals", obj.sub(num1,num2))

else:
    print("invalid input")
```